# Flutter - Map function inside Future method

Tags: flutter, dictionary

How can I run a map function inside a Future method?

This is my code:

```
Future deactivateLogs(List<String> members) async {
  return members.map((member) async {
    return await logDataCollection
      .document('log-$member')
      .updateData({
      'active': false,
    });
  });
}
```

When I call this method, the map function is not being executed. How can I change the syntax so that it runs?

The goal is that the data is being updated in the database (backend) for each of the individual 'member' strings.

The problem can also be made easier:

```
  Future deactivateTribeLogs() {
    List<int> list = [1, 2, 3];
    list.map((e) => print(e));}
```

The map function does not run in this case either.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Not sure what's going on here but you're using Future, await, async and another Future<void>(updateData).

Comment: Hi thanks for your response. I probably mixed up a lot and in a wrong way. What I am trying to achieve is to take all members (Strings in the list) and update a specific document in Firestore. the documents that I want to update are called 'log-member1', 'log-member2' and so on.

Comment: try removing the first return

Comment: I tried it, but it didnt work unfortunately.

Comment: I simplified the problem above. This does also not work. Any idea why?

Comment: use `Future.forEach()` - also check the official docs of `Iterable.map()` - they read: *"This method returns a view of the mapped elements. As long as the returned Iterable is not iterated over, the supplied function f will not be invoked. The transformed elements will not be cached. Iterating multiple times over the returned Iterable will invoke the supplied function f multiple times on the same element."*

Comment: Your simplified version and your non-simplified versions won't work the way you expect for different reasons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two problems:

1. You're using an asynchronous callback with `Iterable.map`, but nothing will wait for the *callbacks* to complete.
2. `Iterable.map` is lazy; if you never attempt to use the result of a callback, it won't bother executing that callback at all. (`Iterable.map` normally is meant for functional-style programming where the callbacks are "pure"; you usually don't want to use it with callbacks that have side-effects.)

When you call `Iterable.map` with an asynchronous callback, it returns an iterable of `Future`s.  If you don't care about execution order of callbacks, you could use `Future.wait` on that directly:

```dart
Future<void> deactivateLogs(List<String> members) async {
  var waitList = members.map((member) async {
    return await logDataCollection.document('log-$member').updateData({
      'active': false,
    });
  });
  await Future.wait(waitList);
}
```

Doing so also will evaluate all elements of the returned list of `Future`s and will avoid your issue with `Iterable.map`'s lazy evaluation.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the definition of [`List::map`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/1.10.1/dart-core/List/map.html), you will see that it returns an `Iterable`, which is not evaluated.

<s>Another way of saying it is that [`List::map`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/1.10.1/dart-core/List/map.html) is lazy and will not run until the iterable is either explicitly iterated or converted to a list.</s>

Actually from the documentation, it says:

> Returns a new **lazy** Iterable with elements that are created by calling f on each element of this Iterable in iteration order.

To fix your problem, just append `.toList()` at the end of the `.map` call, and it will force the iterable to be evaluated.

Since you are not looking to return anything from the function, you can just use [`Future::forEach`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.9.1/dart-async/Future/forEach.html):

```
Future<void> deactivateLogs(List<String> members) =>
  Future.forEach(members, (member) => logDataCollection
      .document('log-$member')
      .updateData({
         'active': false,
      });
  );
```

#### Full example

```
void main() async {
  print('start');
  await deactivateLogs(["Foo", "Bar", "Hello", "World"]);
  print('end');
}

Future<void> deactivateLogs(List<String> members) =>
    Future.forEach(members, (member) {
      final v = await Future(() => member);
      print(v);
    });
```

#### Output

```
start
Foo
Bar
Hello
World
end
```

Comment: `return members.forEach((member) async {` will not work - you need `Future.forEach` (or simple ordinary `for(var e in ...)`) to wait for each async operation

Comment: @pskink While I'm sure your alternatives will work, I am equally positive the example I gave works just as I described it

Comment: try: `void main() async {
  print('start');
  await deactivateLogs(["Foo", "Bar", "Hello", "World"]);
  print('end');
}

void deactivateLogs(List<String> members) async {
  return members.forEach((member) async {
    final v = await Future(() => member);
    print(v);
  });
}` - the output is `start
end
Foo
Bar
Hello
World` which is not that you would expect

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `for loop` for that :

```
Future deactivateLogs(List<String> members) async {
  for(var i = 0; i< members.length; i++) {
    await logDataCollection
      .document('log-' + members[i])
      .updateData({
      'active': false,
    });
  }
  return ;
}
```